# Combining 2 menus [left and right] as one in responsive

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu, responsive-design

I’m going to build a website — the main menu would have 2 menus (left and right) and a logo in between them but how can I combine these menus as one in responsive. Hope you can give me an example code.

[image]

Sorry for my bad english. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use bootstrap to make it responsive, and read the documentation to learn it: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

Comment: @Deer-Outdoor.nl I'm using Bootstrap but only grid system. The menu built by my own.

Comment: Asked many many times before - http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=centered+logo+with+menu

Comment: @Paulie_D This is not a duplicate. The reference you show is of people wanting a centered menu. This OP is asking how to combine 2 menus into one responsively on a small size screen.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to program all your menus beforehand, the two separate menus showing initially on desktop screens, but the combined menu given `display:none` in the CSS. Then in the responsive media query, at smaller screen sizes, set the combined menu to `display:block`, and set the other set of 2 menus to `display:none`.

You don't show your HTML and CSS (it would be good to add these to your question if you want to get any further clarification after this post so we can see what you want), so I don't know how you are doing your menus. But to illustrate the idea I'll just show some very simple pseudo-html in two divs; you put your menus markup inside them:

```
<!-- this is pseudo-markup only! -->
<div id="menu-large-screen">Home   Menu                           Features   Contact</div>
<div id="menu-small-screen">Home   Menu   Features   Contact</div>
```

And your responsive CSS will be:

```
#menu-large-screen { display: block; }
#menu-small-screen { display: none; }

@media all and (max-width: 600px)    /* 600px is just for an example */
{
    #menu-large-screen { display: none; }
    #menu-small-screen { display: block; }
}
```

Both divs will be in the HTML markup, one after the other. But only one will ever show, the one that is *not* display:none for the particular screen size at the time. The other one will not be visible, and will take up no space on screen.

Comment: Thank you for replying but I figured out myself :)